# Selecting some unique rows from an SQLite database, where each row meets a separate criteria

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I need help with generating a query to my SQLite database that, given a list of column names, fetches the same amount of rows. One row for each column in the list must have the value in said column be not null.

### Background

My insult generator selects random words from an SQLite database with numbers representing their respective use cases, where each column is a type of word.

#### wordLibrary

| word | adjective | degree | object | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| extreme | 1 | 2 | NULL | ... |
| very | NULL | 0 | NULL | ... |
| crap | 3 | NULL | 0 | ... |
| bad | NULL | NULL | 0 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

- The `0` under **'degree'** for **'very'** means that it can be used as a degree, without any changes.
- The `3` under **'adjective'** for **'crappy'** means that it can be used as an adjective, by having 'py' added to the end.
- The `NULL` under **'object'** for **'extreme'** means that it can't be used to as an object.

When generating a sentence out of pre-made templates, my python script would make separate queries to the database for each word and then put all the words in the template. The script would, for example, take the template "You are (object)." and generate the following query, to put that word in the template.

```sql
SELECT
    word,
    object,
    random() AS priority
FROM
    wordLibrary
WHERE object NOT NULL
ORDER BY priority
LIMIT 1;
```

If we say that the table above is randomly ordered, the query would select the first row where **'object'** is not null, which would result in the sentence **"You are crap."**. While this wasn't the most efficient, it worked, however...

### The problem

Since some words can be used in several ways, when using a template with several different words, the old solution would sometimes re-use the same word twice in a sentence. If we were to use the template **"You are (degree) (adjective)."**, the old solution could select **'extreme'** as both the **'degree'** and **'adjective'**, which would result in the sentence **"You are extremely extreme."**.

I'd like to solve this by adding the ability to request several words *in a single query*, so that the python script takes a list of word types and returns a list of words. The important thing here is that the query should not use the same word more than once for each query.

If we use the **"You are (degree) (adjective)."** example again, the new solution should randomly order the table and select the first row where **'degree'** is not null and then select the first row, *that hasn't been selected yet*, where **'adjective'** is not null. If the table above is randomly ordered, this would result in the sentence **"You are extremely crappy."**.

Would this be possible to accomplish in a single query that would search for one unique word meeting each criteria, and if so how? Otherwise, should I continue requesting the words individually, but with a filter that removes the already selected words?

Comment: Use subqueries for each criteria, and join them so that the two results are different.

Comment: How can I prevent it from selecting the same row several times?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM (subquery) AS t1 JOIN (subquery) AS t2 ON t1.word != t2.word LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar for the solution. In the **"You are (degree) (adjective)."** example, the query would look like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT word, degree, random() AS priority
        FROM wordLibrary
        WHERE degree NOT NULL
        ORDER BY priority
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS t1
JOIN
    (
        SELECT word, adjective, random() AS priority
        FROM wordLibrary
        WHERE adjective NOT NULL
        ORDER BY priority
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS t2
ON t1.word != t2.word;
```